# How to recover the Harmonic numbers from this function?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, number-theory

The nth Harmonic number is equal to $$ \int_{0}^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} dx.$$ I get how you can show that this is equal to $H_n$ using $\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+...+x^{n-1}$. But when I use Wolfram to find the antiderivative directly, it gives $$ H_n= \int_{0}^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} dx=\left[ \frac{-1\cdot x^{n+1} {}_{1}F_{2}(1,n+1,n+2,x)}{n+1} - \log(1-x)\right]_{0}^{1} .$$

Trying to compute the RHS as $x\to1$ in Wolfram seems to diverge. The RHS evaluated at $1+\epsilon$ just increases it seems. Any help with this?

Comment: Forget wolfram, you were on the right track in the first place. Trust your algebra.

Comment: $\underset{x\to 1}{\text{lim}}\left(-\frac{x^{n+1} \, _2F_1(1,n+1;n+2;x)}{n+1}-\log (1-x)\right)=\underset{x\to 1}{\text{lim}}(-B_x(n+1,0)-\log (1-x))=H_n$.

Comment: Also note that the Hypergeometric function is just a Lerch Transcendent like [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/05/0025/). Also try integrating $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k$$

Comment: Using Wolfram Mathematica the expression `Integrate[ (1 - x^n)/(1 - x), {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> n>-1]` evaluates to `HarmonicNumber[n]` as expected. What Wolfram were you using?

Comment: What sense does it make to evaluate the RHS at $1+\epsilon$, given that $\log(1-x)$ is not defined when $1-x\lt0$?

Comment: @StevenClark thanks for answer, what is the function $B_x$ that you use? Also, how does one get from $ \lim_{x \to 1}(− B_x(n+1,0)−log(1−x)) $ to that equaling $H_n   $? thanks for your help

Comment: $B_x(n+1,0)$ is the incomplete Beta function (see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) which can be represented by the more general hypergeometric $\, _2F_1$ function (see https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/26/01/02/).

Comment: @Somos I believe the OP perhaps evaluated the indefinite integral using Wolfram Alpha because the definite integral exceeds the standard computation time for Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: @BarryCipra $log(z)$ is defined for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ (see https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/04/01/), but you can also approach $x\to 1$ from below instead of above in which case $1-x>0$.

Comment: Using Wolfram Mathematica again `Limit[Integrate[ (1-x^n)/(1-x), {x,0,x}, Assumptions -> n>-1], x->1, Direction -> "FromBelow"] //FullSimplify` evaluates to `HarmonicNumber[n]` as expected again.

Comment: @StevenClark yeah I was using alpha and not mathematica, should have thought of that.

Comment: @StevenClark, I think there are some complex analysts who would disagree with what wolfram has to say about $\log z$ being an analytic function on the complex plane, mapping (all of) $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @BarryCipra The articles at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Logarithm.html provide more information on complex logarithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Steven Clark suggested, let’s use a similar fact. Also note that the Hypergeometric function is just a [Lerch Transcendent](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html) like [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/05/0025/) in your question.

> $$F_2(1,n+1,n+2,x)=\,_2\text F_1(1,n+1;n+2;x)$$

Also try integrating $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k$:

Therefore we have the following partial sums:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^kdx=[-x^{n+1}Φ(x,1,n+1)-\ln(1-x)]_0^1=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1^{k+1}-0}{k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{k+1}=\text H_n$$

If you do not prefer the link:

$$Φ(x,1,n+1) =\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k+n+1},|x|<1$$
Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: The answer is $\,H_n.$

Comment: Is it possible to derive it from just $[-x^{n+1}Φ(x,1,n+1)-x-\ln(1-x)]_0^1$ though? Like I'm confused how it can evaluate to $H_n$ when it is undefined when trying to evaluate it at 1.

Comment: The sum inside the integral should start with $k=0$ instead of $k=1$ similar to the other sums. Also $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}=-x^{n+1} \Phi (x,1,n+1)-\log (1-x)$ (there is no $-x$ term in the result).

Comment: Also the approach in your answer is only valid for non-negative integer values of $n$ whereas the Hypergeometric and Beta representations are more generally valid for $n\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Somos the result is fixed. Thanks,

Comment: I know there is a conversion formula from incomplete beta function to lerch transcendent, but you can derive it using @StevenClark ‘s beta representation which would extend the lerch transcendent in a way.